# Json result wrapped in pre tag - how to get value of it

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

This is first time that I work with json. I am trying to return Json from my action method:

```
public JsonResult Upload()
{
   ...
   return Json(new { foo = "sos....sos....sos..."});
}
```

But in result all I get is my message wrap in this "pre" tag. How to parse "foo" from this?

```
"<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"foo":"sos....sos....sos..."}</pre>"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the reason you are receiving the data wrapped in a pre tag is because you are requesting the data as HTML and not plain text or json.

Try specifying the data type as json to stop the response being converted to HTML.

Comment: Am using `header('Content-Type: application/json')` in PHP on Chrome. Seems that output is wrapped in a pre with an added tab despite the header.

Comment: I think @Fenchurch better answers this question, which is not how to avoid the `pre` tag, but how to get its contents.

Comment: @ProfK This is a much better answer, OP doesn't want the `pre` tag.. they are only asking how to parse the foo out because they don't know they can avoid it. Why convert from json to html then back to json?

Answer (score 4):

This returns the content of the first pre tag with the class "yourclass".

```
document.querySelector("pre.yourclass").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the handler on the client side is trying to ensure that the server's response is well formed HTML. I believe some javascript libraries with file upload support will wrap non-HTML repsonses in the  tag as you describe. A very non-intuitive solution might be to set the mimetype at the server to be "text/html", so that the ajax handler doesn't try to wrap the response.