# Access JSON returned by Controller in View

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to serialize my linq to JSON.
My issue is 
[Json result wrapped in pre tag - how to get value of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559461/json-result-wrapped-in-pre-tag-how-to-get-value-of-it). The answer is not what I am looking for though.
Here are my code
**Controller**

```
return Json(regionBoudaries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I see that my JSON string is written in the page
Now I am writing something like something like

**View**

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    initialize(); 
    process(a_variable);
}
```

How can I set the `a_variable` the value of the JSon returned from controller.
Please help me out. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you tell us how you are calling your controller action which returns the JSON?  Usually we see a pattern where one controller action is called to render a view, and then some client javascript code in that view calls another controller action to retrieve and process some JSON.  It looks like you maybe are trying to do this in one step rather than two steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public class SomeType RegionBoudaries { get; set; }

    ... some other properties
}
```

and then have the controller action serving this view populate the property of the view model:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.RegionBoudaries = ... same stuff as in your other action
    return View(model);
}
```

and then in the corresponding strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        var a_variable = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.RegionBoudaries));
        initialize(); 
        process(a_variable);
    });
</script>
```